# How to get additional information for each Kafka client (producer/consumer) metric?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

According to [Apache Kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/28/documentation.html#consumer_fetch_monitoring), bytes-consumed-rate metric should contain the tags: client-id and topic, but I am only seeing the tags client-id and node-id. Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong here?

Also, is there a way to get additional information (like broker urls, consumer group name, etc.) in the form of tags?

Consumer client code:

```
    kafkaConsumer.subscribe(kafkaTopicNames);

    while (true) {
        try {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> consumerRecords = kafkaConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000));

            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord : consumerRecords) {
                logger.info("Message received " + consumerRecord.value());
            }

            Map<MetricName, ? extends Metric> kafkaConsumerMetrics = kafkaConsumer.metrics();

            for (MetricName metricName: kafkaConsumerMetrics.keySet()) {
                Map<String, String> metricNameTags = metricName.tags();

                logger.info(">>> Kafka consumer metric tags: " + metricNameTags);
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {}

        break;
    }
```

Output:

```
>>> Kafka consumer metric tags: {client-id=this-is-a-consumer-id}
>>> Kafka consumer metric tags: {client-id=this-is-a-consumer-id}
>>> Kafka consumer metric tags: {client-id=this-is-a-consumer-id}
>>> Kafka consumer metric tags: {client-id=this-is-a-consumer-id, node-id=node-xxxxx}
.
.
.
```

Comment: No, consumers don't know about broker urls to include in tags. If you want to get broker server metadata, best to use Prometheus JMX + Node exporter on the brokers, rather than write your own metric gatherer... Also, print the metric name if you want to actually compare against the documentation

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer! That makes sense. But I am not even getting topic tag. If you look at the Apache Kafka documentation, you'll see the following line: kafka.consumer:type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics,client-id="{client-id}",topic="{topic}"

Comment: Those are JMX metrics in the docs... Not sure `consumer.metrics()` method is the exact same data